# Selenium Webdriver warning - Invalid token "screen"

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am new in Selenium Webdriver. When i use this code then i got both output and an WARNING. Please help me, How can i ignore this warning. My code is:

```
package com.webdriver.Webdriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface,
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get( "https://mobile.twitter.com/andres/about" );
        // Find the text input element by its name
        //WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//title"));
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='footer']/strong/a"));
        String s=element.getText();
        // Enter something to search for
        //element.sendKeys( "Cheese!" );
        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        //element.submit();
        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println( "Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        System.out.println(s);
        driver.quit();
        }

}
```

WARNING:

> Nov 30, 2011 2:54:23 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
>
> WARNING: CSS error: [1:1724] Error in @media rule. Invalid token "screen". Was expecting one of: , , .
>
> Nov 30, 2011 2:54:23 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
>
> WARNING: CSS warning: [1:1724] Ignoring the whole rule.
>
> Nov 30, 2011 2:54:23 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
>
> WARNING: CSS error: [1:1908] Error in @media rule. Invalid token "screen". Was expecting one of: , , .
>
> Nov 30, 2011 2:54:23 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
>
> WARNING: CSS warning: [1:1908] Ignoring the whole rule.
>
> Nov 30, 2011 2:54:23 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
>
> WARNING: CSS error: [1:3437] Error in @media rule. Invalid token "screen". Was expecting one of: , , .
>
> Nov 30, 2011 2:54:23 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
>
> WARNING: CSS warning: [1:3437] Ignoring the whole rule.
>
> Page title is: Twitter
>   Refresh now

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You will need to implement your own `HtmlUnitDriver` subclass, and then set the `cssErrorHandler` to a `SilentCssErrorHandler` instance.

This can easily be done with an inner-class, override the constructor and setting the error handler:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.SilentCssErrorHandler;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public abstract class MyBaseTestCase {
    protected HtmlUnitDriver webDriver = new SilentHtmlUnitDriver();

    protected class SilentHtmlUnitDriver extends HtmlUnitDriver {
        SilentHtmlUnitDriver() {
            super();
            this.getWebClient().setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can extend this base class, and access the webDriver object and enjoy spam-free output!

Answer (score 1):

The CSS file for the page `https://mobile.twitter.com/andres/about` contains unexpected/unsupported/broken code.

You have two options: Replace the `DefaultCssErrorHandler` with a [`SilentCssErrorHandler`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/SilentCssErrorHandler.html) or replace it with a default implementation that just filters these specific errors (match the error message against the strings you see in the output).

To install your custom handler:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(); // Can't use generic driver anymore
driver.getWebClient().setCssErrorHandler(handler); // install your handler
```

Comment: `getWebClient()` is not a public method.

Comment: The code above is a copy&paste from my project. If the method isn't public anymore, either get the source code and make it public or use reflection to call it anyway. *sigh* Don't you hate it too when unit testing libraries fight with you?